# Using dropzone.js in asp.net (Web Form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js for uploading the file in .aspx application
So Can we get Image property(Like Image height and width) after uploading file for doing some client side animation

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({
        url: 'BatchUpload_New.aspx',
    paramName: "files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 102, // MB
    enqueueForUpload: false,
    accept: function (file, done) {

        return done();
    }
    });
});
```

**.aspx**

```
 <div id="frmMain" runat="server" class="dropzone">
                <div>
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                    </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    foreach (string s in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];

        if (file != null)
        {
            string fileExtension = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            }

            // IMPORTANT! Make sure to validate uploaded file contents, size, etc. to prevent scripts being uploaded into your web app directory
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\", Guid.NewGuid()+ fileExtension);
            file.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            lbTtest.Text += " " + file.FileName;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am using your code, could you please give me information, how to trigger code-behind  "foreach" loop?

Answer (score 1):

Dropzone adds data to the file object you can use when events fire. You can access file.width and file.height if it's an image, as well as file.upload which is an object containing: progress (0-100), total (the total bytes) and bytesSent.